# How to create C++ Macro like DECODE function in SQL?

Tags: c++, macros

Currently in C++ I have to write code like this to transform values:

```
    if (a == 1) {
        b = "one";
    } else if (a == 2) {
        b = "two"
    } else if (a == 3) {
        b = "three"
    } else {
        b = "too_big"
    }
```

How to create a macro DECODE like in SQL so I can use code like this:

```
b = DECODE(a, 1, "one", 2, "two", 3, "three", "too_big");
```

Comment: Try something with variadic parameters.

Comment: Is the parameter list fix or variadic?

Comment: The param list is variadic, so we can use macro in many places.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit rusty in C, and would have used a variadic function. But with a macro...

First a functioning expression (I hope):

```
b = (char* s[] = {"one", "two", "three", "too_big"}, 
     int n = sizeof(s) / sizeof(char*),
     s[(a >= n ? n : a) - 1]);
```

Then what could become of that:

```
b = DECODE(a, { "one", "two", "three", "too_big" });
```

Which is not quite the same.

So the macro:

```
#define DECODE(a, sss) (char* s[] = sss, \
            int n = sizeof(s) / sizeof(char*), s[(a >= n ? n : a) - 1])
```

A variadic function being better.
A `switch` statement my natural choice. Or:

```
 b = a == 1 ? "one"
   : a == 2 ? "two"
   : a == 3 ? "three"
   : "too_big";
```

Comment: Thanks. I think functioning expression requires more resource. I prefer DECODE macro because it is more readable (at least to me). But there is not easy solution then use Switch is better.